# 6 Figures which fill out the page

Tags: floats

So I am using the code below to make 6 figures on one page:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]  
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/Normal/EXAbs}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/Normal/HXAbs}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]  
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/Normal/EYAbs}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/Normal/HYAbs}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}[ht]  
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/Normal/EZAbs}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bilder/Normal/HZAbs}
  \end{minipage}
 \caption{Vergleich zwischen Momentenmethode und Dipolapproximation der Amplituden des elektrischen und magnetischen Feldes aufgeschlüsselt nach ihren Komponenten}
\end{figure}
```

Problem is it leaves a hughe gap at the bottom of the Page.

[image: Hughe Space in the Bottom]

But when i make my figures bigger like `{0.5\textwidth}`. Only 4 Figures stay one one page. The other two are getting pushed onto the next page despite having a huge amount of space left. I would like to make them bigger or at least center the whole figure.

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[p]` and only _one_ `figure` environment

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You should put all six figures in a single `\begin{figure}[p]...\end{figure}` to ensure they are the same page.  You may then be able to use something like `\vspace{2cm plus 1fill}` between rows to fill the vertical height

Comment: Welp, that was an easy enough fix. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include all the images in a single

```
\begin{figure}[p]...\end{figure}
```

this will ensure that the images lie on a single separate page.  You do not need to place the images in minipages, you can just specify their widths and provide space between them with `\hspace{1cm}`.  Between each row you can add vertical space with `\vspace{3cm}`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

  \vspace{3cm}

  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

  \vspace{3cm}

  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

  \caption{Full page collection of figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats just perfect. Even better than what i had. Thank you very much.